# Making AWS Product Advertising API Request iOS

Tags: ios, api, amazon-advertising-api

Today i have been unable to make a request for an "ItemSearch" request for the product advertising api for aws.

First off, this was working Monday Feburary 24th and now March 1st it does not work. I don't know if there was any updates that may have changed the way AWS works. I couldn't find anything when searching.

My first error is: *"Request has expired. Timestamp date is 140301235753Z"* this means that the time i enter for the request "140301235753Z" is 15 minutes out of range of what AWS has stored for the UTC time. I do a bit of research and end up changing the code below.

```
NSDateFormatter *UTCFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
UTCFormatter.dateFormat = @"yyMMddHHmmss'Z'";
UTCFormatter.timeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"UTC"];

NSString *timeStamp = [UTCFormatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];
```

i changed the `@"yyMMddHHmmss'Z'"` to `@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'"`

Re-running the request again i came across this error: *"The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your AWS Secret Access Key and signing method."* this means that the signature portion of the API call that i calculate is wrong when comparing the one AWS calculates when it receives my request.

I have used this link [Amazon Signature Examples](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/signature-v4-examples.html) as a reference to check my code below.

```
// create HMAC with SHA256
const char *cKey  = [secretKey cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
const char *cData = [canonicalString cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
unsigned char cHMAC[CC_SHA256_DIGEST_LENGTH];

CCHmac(kCCHmacAlgSHA256, cKey, strlen(cKey), cData, strlen(cData), cHMAC);

NSData *hashData = [NSData dataWithBytes:cHMAC length:CC_SHA256_DIGEST_LENGTH];
NSString *signature = [[DTBase64Coding stringByEncodingData:hashData] stringByURLEncoding];
```

I don't see an error with my code. I have looked, via google, for an application that may be able to create the string i desire in order to test if my signature is correct, but AWS didn't seem to have anything (that i could find, i could just be a bad googler).

My secret key for the AWS had a "/" character in it. I thought this might be messing with the algorithms for calculating the HMAC. So i created new secret keys until amazon generated me one with out odd characters and tested it. It did not work....

Ultimately what i am trying to make is an AWS Product Advertising API Request using this information

```
NSString *verb = @"GET";
NSString *hostName = @"webservices.amazon.com";
NSString *path = @"/onca/xml";

NSDictionary *params = @{
                         @"Service": @"AWSECommerceService",
                         @"AWSAccessKeyId": accessKey,
                         @"Operation": @"ItemSearch",
                         @"ResponseGroup": @"Large",
                         @"SearchIndex": @"Books",
                         @"Title": bookTitle,
                         @"AssociateTag" : trackingID
                         };
```

I have substituted sensitive/dynamic information with variables.

I have searched through the documentation PDFs at [AWS Product Advertising Documentation](http://aws.amazon.com/archives/Product-Advertising-API/8967000559514506) and can't seem to figure out my problem.

The most baffling part is that my code was working 6 days ago and i have changed nothing.

Comment: hey A'sa, did you find the solutions of your problem, I'm facing the same issue...

Comment: I made a noobie mistake and commented out the code that encoded the body parameters. If you are having a similar issues i would verify that your url is correct and that the body has the correct parameters :3

Answer (score 0):

I've had a similar experience with another third party API. Apparently my request was being redirected and I had to resign my request.

Be sure to sign your request in this nsurlrequest delegate method:

```
- (NSURLRequest *)connection: (NSURLConnection *)inConnection
             willSendRequest: (NSURLRequest *)inRequest
            redirectResponse: (NSURLResponse *)inRedirectResponse;
```

Comment: My method of retrieving the XML from this URL is encapsulated in NSXMLParser via 

NSXMLParser* xmlParser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:xmlURL];
    xmlParser.delegate = self;

Answer (score 0):

I made a noob mistake and commented out the code that encoded the body parameters. After uncommenting it and setting the values it all worked fine. So make sure you encode your parameters.